# Matching a Low Variable matrix field with custom channel field

Tags: matrix, custom-fields, low-variables

Hopefully this will be easy to sort.

One of my custom channel fields is a select dropdown.

I have created a low variable matrix field, which contains two columns.

Column 1 is "Name" & Column 2 is "Description"

When displaying the single entry, I want it to show the name & description in my markup, based on what was selected in the custom field.

Not quite sure how to do this.

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_custom"}
<h5>Random text to display {name}</h5>
<p>{description}</p>
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Thats my starting point, but I need to somehow make it match the Name against the name that is selected in the custom field.

Any ideas? Thanks.

or I'm open to a better way of doing it!

**EDIT**
I've scrapped it for now. Think I was over complicating things.

Gone with this instead in my within my channel entries tag...

```
<h5>Random Text<strong>{custom_field}</strong></h5>
{if custom_field =="Option One"}<p>Description One.</p>{/if}
{if custom_field =="Option Two"}<p>Description Two</p>{/if}
{if custom_field =="Option Three"}<p>Description Three</p>{/if}
```

Ideally I wanted a way to control the Descriptions within the CP, as opposed to hard coding it, but this works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: A little confused. How does your Select menu custom field relate to the Low Variables field? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Maybe you can add the channel:entries code to your question as well? That will help in understanding what you're doing.

Comment: If you are manually editing the options of the custom field, why not replace <p>Description One.</p> etc with low variables? (Separate text fields, not a matrix field) `{if custom_field =="Option One"}{lv_description_one}{/if}`

Comment: Yep, thats an option actually. Might do that. Trying to cut down as much code & hard coded items in my templates as much as possible, so that will help! Thanks!

Comment: @JasonVarga, we're trying to clean up old, unanswered questions. Since your comment led to the answer, could you repost it as an answer below? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are manually editing the options of the custom field, why not replace `<p>Description One.</p>` etc with low variables? (Separate text fields, not a matrix field)

```
{if custom_field =="Option One"}{lv_description_one}{/if}
```